# How to change NaN value with 0 in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I've got the below expression and even though I thought I was handling 'NaN' values properly I still get them when I click preview. Does anybody know how to change it, so that NaN values get replaced with 0. Thanks.

**=0 + Sum(IIF(IsNothing(Fields!value.Value) = True, 0, Fields!value.Value)) / IIF(Information.IsNothing(Fields!value.Value) = True, 0, CountDistinct(Fields!Introducer.Value))**

Answer (score 0):

NaN means that the SSRS couldn't calculate the value. Looking at your expression, looks like it's because you could very easily end up with a divide by 0. If I understand your expression correct, I would do:

```
IIf(IsNothing(Fields!value.Value) OR (CountDistinct(Fields!Introducer.Value) = 0), 0,  Fields!value.Value / CountDistinct(Fields!Introducer.Value))
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, there are some instances in my data where I end up with a divide by 0. Your expression seems to be working, however, it's not doing the right calculation. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think correcting the original code with the suggested solution would work: = 0 + Sum(IIF(CountDistinct(Fields!Introducer.Value)= 0 OR IsNothing(Fields!value.Value) =True, 0, Fields!value.Value)) / IIF(CountDistinct(Fields!Introducer.Value)= 0, 1, CountDistinct(Fields!Introducer.Value))

Comment: If the expression is yielding a result which is not accurate, you may want to format the 0 and 1 by typing this as 0.0 and 1.0 and/or using the CDEC function.  Otherwise you might be seeing some rounding you don't expect.